# ASP.NET CORE Authentication Correlation Failed only on iOS/Safari

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core

When I try to log in on iOS/Safari I get the below error. If I refresh the page the error still occurs, but if I go to the url bar and press "Go" I am successfully logged in. On Android (Chrome and Edge) and desktop (Chrome and Brave) I am logged in without a problem. Anyone know what could be the problem?

I have tried different solutions suggested by others here on stackoverflow, but it didn't help me with my problem.

The error:

> **An unhandled execption occured while processing the request**
>
> Exception: Correlation failed.
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler.HandleRequestAsync()
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddlevare.Invoke(HttpContext context)
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var keysDirectoryName = "thekey";
    var keysDirectoryPath = Path.Combine(hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath, keysDirectoryName);
    if (!Directory.Exists(keysDirectoryPath))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(keysDirectoryPath);
    }

    services.AddDataProtection()
            .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(keysDirectoryPath))
            .SetApplicationName("thename")
            .SetDefaultKeyLifetime(TimeSpan.FromDays(90));

    services.AddControllersWithViews();

    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })

    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.LoginPath = "/";
        options.LogoutPath = "/signout";
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(365);
        options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        options.Cookie.Domain = "thedomain.com";
        options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
    })



    .AddFacebook(options =>
    {
        options.AppId = "theid";
        options.AppSecret = "thesecret";
        options.CallbackPath = "/signin-facebook";
        options.SaveTokens = true;
    });

    services.Configure<SecurityStampValidatorOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.ValidationInterval = TimeSpan.FromDays(7);
    });

        ...
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    ...
}
```

The controller action

```
public async Task<IActionResult> LogIn([FromForm] string provider, [FromForm] string redirectto)
{
    ...

    return Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { AllowRefresh = true, IsPersistent = true, ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(365), RedirectUri = "/auth/validation/" + redirectto }, provider);
}
```